# R kernel - Custom CSS in Jupyter notebook that works in nbviewer

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

When working with Jupyter Notebooks with a Python kernel, I just type the code below to apply my custom css file, which live in the same repository as my Notebook. It works like a charm when rendered by nbviewer.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
def css():
    style = open("../css/custom.css", "r").read()
return HTML(style)
css()
```

Now I am working in a Notebook with an **R kernel**, so the code above does not work. Is there an R equivalent to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
cssFile <- '../css/custom.css'
IRdisplay::display_html(readChar(cssFile, file.info(cssFile)$size))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It just displays the CSS in the cell's output. It doesn't actually apply it to the page.